# Android / ASP - How to display PDF from page generated using ASP.NET hosted in Android webview?

Tags: android, asp.net, pdf, android-webview

I'm presented with a peculiar problem that hopefully someone can help me with.

The Android app I'm working on contains a journey that is entirely web-based; the app itself has fragment that contains a webview, and we load the web journey into that webview.

As part of that web journey, we want to allow the user to click on a link to download a PDF document that should open in the user's chosen PDF viewer.

Initially, we tried to implement this by intercepting requests from the webview that either had the URL end with ".pdf" or had a request header of "Accept: application/pdf".  We would then hand these requests over to OkHttp (appending the session cookie from Android's CookieManager) and perform the request using the app's native framework.  We could then handle the response natively, save the PDF locally and open it via an intent.

However, we found that this didn't work, as the web journey's pages are generated server-side using ASP.NET.  The link the user clicks on to download the PDF has its target set to "viewDocument.aspx?id=" and so the request doesn't fulfil either of the above conditions (it does not end with ".pdf" and does not have the "Accept: application/pdf" header).

Can anyone help in how to download and display a PDF from a site that is generated using ASP.NET and hosted in an Android webview?

Comment: displaying pdf and the separate issue of what happens when you try to send a pdf to the client side for download? (2 different issues). You can't force from server side control what Android does. You CAN force a display of PDF by using PDF.js server side. So, you have PDF display solved. A download button on the page where you steam the pdf to client? That will show a button, and in most cases after download Android will display the pdf. Client Android software is required to change this behavior.  But forcing display can be done with server side PDF.js. So that should suffice quite nice